# Set a check box to false in Preference Activity

Tags: android, xml, preferences

I am trying to implement user preferences. A problem I have is that if one of my check boxes is ticked I want to set the other to false. I know about dependency and from what I have seen it doesn't change the value. Just disables you from changing the preference. What can I do to change a checkbox to false if another is true? This is my xml:

```
   <PreferenceCategory android:title="Launch Settings">
    <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="enable_nearest_station"
            android:title="Nearest station"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:summary="Will launch your nearest station on startup" 
            android:disableDependentsState="true"/>
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="enable_default_station"
    android:title="Default station"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:dependency="enable_nearest_station"
    android:summary="Allows you to choose a default to launch with."
    />
```

```
       />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the set `setOnPreferenceChangeListener(Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener onPreferenceChangeListener)` to your CheckBoxPreference and code to set false other CheckBoxPreference.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I feel stupid for asking but how do I get the value of the check box preference? Thanks

Comment: To verify I know how to get the actual preference. findPreference